# AIR ApplicationUpdater authentication

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, auto-update

Is it possible to create an ApplicationUpdater in an AIR app that uses some sort of authentication (perhaps HTTP Basic) to download updates from the server? I want to enable auto-updating in a proprietary application, so it doesn't make sense to upload updates to a publicly accessible web location, since only people who already have the application should be able to get updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this what you wrote the right way you just use XML on your Server which will at start up read out IF OR IF NOT to update just the same way the ADOBE updater works, and with that you can use true / false etc. at least that how I did it with some of my AIR Applications! all can be enforced (visible or invisible) or just by the user done like YES / NO etc. endless options. regards aktell

Comment: Thank you! I am using the built-in tools to check if there's an update available, and then I have my code take over to authenticate and download it.